# datadog parse timestamp pattern from JSON

Tags: datadog

Trying to parse this simple json log in the DATADOG pipeling processor, but can't find sufficent documentation. I am trying to parse the timestamp : 2022-05-22T06:10:31.563000 so the logs in datadog match the ones in my logs

```
{"login_time": "2022-05-22T06:10:31.563000", "login_name": "nicesrvcdev", "host_name": "BOB_MARLEY", "program_name": "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query"}
```

Comment: Datadog should understand directly JSON
"Datadog automatically parses JSON-formatted logs. For other formats, Datadog allows you to enrich your logs with the help of Grok Parser." [doc](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_configuration/parsing/) 

Are you looking to do something particular? If this is a nested JSON, you can check [this grok parsing option](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_configuration/parsing/?tab=matchers#nested-json)

Comment: I editd my question, I bassically need datadog to parse the timestamp

Answer (score 3):

> The recognized date formats are: ISO8601, UNIX (the milliseconds EPOCH format), and RFC3164.

https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_configuration/processors/?tab=ui#log-date-remapper

---

Create a grok parser using the [advanced setting to target](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_configuration/parsing/?tab=matchers#parsing-a-specific-text-attribute) the `login_time` attribute from your log.

`rule %{date("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"):date}`

[image: grok parser screenshot]
https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_configuration/parsing/?tab=matchers#parsing-dates

Then use the date remapper on that `date` attribute now that it's in a recognized format.

Comment: Thanks so much, your help is appreciated